# android device as Digital Media Renderer (the DMR of DLNA)?

Tags: media-player, dlna

So I have this cheap MK802 android devince connected to my old TV, I want MK802 to be as a digital TV box, which could receive pushed media content from DLNA sources.

Are there any good DMR app for android? I tried:

- com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp
- com.waxrain.airplayer

Both can browse remote DMS contents and play them, BubbleUPNP can control my Windows Media Player, but they can NOT receive push pictures, videos, etc.

- What's wrong with my home network?
- Are there any better alternative DMR apps for android?
- What can I do to diagnose the problem?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do at least some UPnP operations, there is nothing wrong with your network.

Capability of browsing DMS (aka UPnP **pull**) does not imply a capability of receiving commanded content from DMS/DMC (aka UPnP **push**). DMR has a separate set of optional functions for pushing, which may or may not be implemented.

The simplest way of diagnosing is to start DeviceSpy from [Intel UPnP Developer Tools](http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp) (Windows application). That will give you all devices in local network, which do publish some UPnP interfaces. The one you are looking for is `AVTransport` (UPnP namespace intentionally omitted). *No AVTransport means no push*. You should see at least a core function `SetAVTransportURI` there. Don't be surprised if some DMR software does not show up at all. Capability of browsing DMS and playing content from it does not require publishing any UPnP interfaces. DMC does not publish any interfaces itself either, it just knows how to operate other UPnP interfaces.

About the lack of push-capable DMR implementations for Android: push means that the software must be capable of sitting there with an open port and just waiting for commands from any DMC. My wild theory is that this somehow doesn't align with what Android applications can or should do. The fact is that i have BubbleUPnP and UPnPPlay myself on my Android and i confirm that neither implement push. You can try the rest of [Wiki list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients#Android) and let me know the result :)

Comment: Hi, I upvote for you because the awesome Intel UPnP tool. I found that `com.waxrain.airplayer` as a matter of fact, implements the `AVTransport` interface. The author specifically claims its DMR role. I even made it play some avi from a http source using the Intel UPnP Device Spy. The app & android device now shows up on Win7 home network, but still timeout after send .avi through Win7 Explorer "Play To" menu. What further options do I have?

Comment: I'm afraid this airplayer isn't very stable with regards to push. I have installed it myself and tried to push a plain MP3 to it from 4 different controllers (Intel devtools one, manually through DeviceSpy invocation, Windows Media Player, Songbird). Didn't succeed, not once. You might have been lucky to get through once. Further options, well try as many other Android DMRs as you can :) Start with the Wiki mentioned.

Comment: Argh, i can't even quit the app. Had to kill it :(

Answer (score 1):

UPnPlay works very nicely for me using Windows Media Player 12 "Play to" feature. Recent versions of BubbleUpnP support DLNA push, although it doesn't seem to support remote volume control even though it pretends to. Also has problem if you jump around in the list in WMP. aVia Media Player works ok, but no remote volume control and similar problems if you try to jump around through multiple tracks remotely. Other apps should handle push as well (MediaHouse UPnP / DLNA Browser, ArkMC DLNA Media Center) but I haven't tried them. I couldn't get AnDLNA or WiFi Oh Player to work with push.