# Android streaming music from desktop, controlled by another android!

Tags: streaming, remote-control, dlna

I just got a Samsung Galaxy S3, and I can't think of a better use for my old Galaxy S than tucking it away on a shelf with an audio cable hooked up to my a/v receiver, streaming music from my desktop upstairs.  All this works fine, but I have to jump up and down to control what gets played. Now I want the ability to control the music from my new phone, so it's always a pocket away.

I currently use, ugh, I think it's iMediaShare Lite on the old phone, and it streams great using DLNA with either tversity or windows media player on my desktop. Now I just need a way to control it from the other phone. Is there a combination of apps that lets me do this?

I've looked into XBMC and stuff, but it doesn't seem to run well yet on android, and all the XBMC remotes seem to operate like regular TV remotes; they assume you're looking at a screen, so they don't offer song picking abilities directly on the remote app screen.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a software which acts as an UPnP *Control Point* on your new phone, and a *Media Renderer with Push* on the old phone. A control point is capable of exactly what you need: browse *Media Server* (your desktop) in the same way as you do with your old phone currently, but it doesn't play itself, instead it tells the *Renderer* "hey, start streaming that URL". Then it just observes the *Renderer* and can control the playback (if *Renderer* supports being controlled). That "being controlled" part is called "Media Push": instead of browsing the *Server* from *Renderer* directly, the *Controller* tells the *Renderer* what to do.

Finding a *Control Point* for Android should be easy (i won't present any suggestions, just google "Android UPnP Control Point"). There is a solid chance that iMediaShare is a *Control Point* already. But i am afraid that *Renderer with Push* for Android is hard to find. It essentialy means that the phone must sit on the network with opened server socket, doing nothing, waiting for commands. And that's perhaps problematic with Android. I already answered [one question here on a similar matter](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32726/android-device-as-digital-media-renderer-the-dmr-of-dlna) and the asker didn't report any conclusion. You are welcome to pioneer the search for such Android app :-)

Comment: Thanks. Very informative. The only thing I found that came close was com.waxrain.airplayer mentioned in the thread you linked, but that played music for about 2 seconds then buffered indefinitely. Hopefully someone will come up with something... Or maybe I'll go back and try getting into Android development myself :(